# Git issues with cyrillic symbols

Tags: git

i have some troubles when i trying to type `git status`

It looks like this [image: cyrillic symbols]

Directory path looks like Локальный диск С:/Пользователи/admin/IdeaProjects/main/src

So because of this i cant add any files that i needed

I tryed to fix this problem with this [guide](https://habrahabr.ru/post/74839/) but cannot find quotepath in core section, its just empty, but if trying to put it manually, i getting failure with this error "bad numeric config value"

How could i fix that without renaming cyrillic symbols in directory?

Comment: When i trying to type `git add HelloWorld.java` or `git add C:/users/admin/ideaprojects/main/src/Helloworld.java"` nothing happens

Comment: how are you setting the `quotepath` property? Try `git config core.quotepath false`, it should work.

Comment: alternatively, try [`git bash`](https://gitforwindows.org/)

Comment: you can also try creating a symlink to your `IdeaProjects` directory with latin letters using [`junction` command as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/1020821/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-on-windows-10#1020825). This way your path won't have any Russian character.

Comment: could you copy the relevant information from console as a text. It would help to find it by others and frankly I don't see anything with those colors with a phone.

Comment: Was only mine mistake, i was creating repository firstly with `git init` instead of typing `cd` to let path for the directory that i needed, thanks for help.